# Cannot update Looker Studio data sources due to bugged persistence of "Changed Semantic Configuration"

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I, like [many other people](https://www.google.com/search?q=looker%20studio%20%22Changed%20Semantic%20Configuration%22%20site%3Asupport.google.com&sca_esv=572750083&bshm=rime%2F1) have experienced issues with Looker Studio being unable to update a data source because of the `Changed Semantic Configuration` error. People have had this issue since 2020 and I would not be using Looker Studio if I were not forced to do so.

This is typically caused when you delete columns on a Google sheet causing looker studio to lose its mind when trying to find the columns.

To briefly describe my workflow, it consists of:

- First creating a Looker Studio data source (`Create > Data source)` and pointing it to a Google sheet (DO NOT add it manually directly to a report, this is always buggy).
- Creating another data source using the `Extract Data` Google connector. This extracts only the relevant and filtered data from the first data source, and its easier to do all preprocessing and calculated fields here if necessary. I don't know why, but it won't let me extract data directly from the Google sheet, hence the need for the first step.
- Create a report, using the extracted data source.

Why separate the data with 3 layers of abstraction away from the dashboard? Because connecting it directly to the sheet makes the dashboard break if there is the slightest single character change to the sheet schema. This way, if anything breaks, I can fix it in the `extract data` step before errors hit the dashboard. The downside is that the data is not real-time, you can only automate extraction once a day.

With this system at least I can rename columns, all I have to do is refresh the first datasets fields, and extract the second dataset, and nothing breaks in the dashboard.

However, deleting columns, or adding columns, occassionally generates a `Changed Semantic Configuration` warning when you refresh fields, that will never disappear. What is a `Changed Semantic Configuration`? Nobody has any clue and Google is unwilling to help with that regard. The problem here is the data extraction refuses to run if this error is present, so you are unable to update your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is to go to the first looker studio data source (not the Google sheet itself), `Edit connection > worksheet` and switch the worksheet to anything else and `reconnect`. This will cause it to drop all fields and add the new ones in the other worksheet. Then switch the worksheet back and `reconnect`. This will add all the original columns back, this time (hopefully) with no `Changed Semantic Configuration` error.

Then you can go to the extracted dataset, and re-extract. It might throw an error (as it takes some time to register a change in the source), but keep refreshing the first data source and retrying the extract and it should work, and recognise all the columns correctly. I can confirm that as of `2023-10-12` this has worked for me to drop 2 columns.

It is a shame that since `2020` such a simple bug is forcing Looker Studio users to rebuild whole dashboards, and that Google is unwilling to support any of their own products properly.